# Banshee Compiling on Ubuntu 16.04 fails

Tags: compiling, music, banshee, compiler

At the moment, I am trying to compile banshee from git: http://banshee.fm/download/development/, but it fails.

I am doing this because I plan to fix something in the Banshee's source code.

Here is the actual output from ./autogen.sh:

```
checking for GST_SHARP... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gstreamer-sharp-1.0 >= 0.99.0) were not met:

No package 'gstreamer-sharp-1.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
```

When I try to compile gstreamer-sharp: https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp/tree/1.0 this is the result:

```
checking for GLIB_SHARP... no
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-sharp-3.0 >= 2.99.4) were not met:

Requested 'glib-sharp-3.0 >= 2.99.4' but version of GLib is 2.99.3

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GLIB_SHARP_CFLAGS
and GLIB_SHARP_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I am also interested in this if you figured out how to get around this.